# Do not understand the meaning of "except that E1 is evaluated only once"

Tags: java, jls

I have seen the following phrase from JLS quoted very often:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent
>   to E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1
>   is evaluated only once.

However, I do not understand the meaning of "except that E1 is evaluated only once".
Under what scenario does "E1" get evaluated twice?

Comment: If E1 was an expression such as `x[y++]`.  Using `E1 op= E2` the `++` only occurs once, but using the longer form `++` would occur twice and y would get incremented twice.

Comment: So for "E1 += E2" case, if E1 was "x[y++]" then y would be incremented only once, even if this statement is equivalent to "E1 = (T)(E1) + (E2)). 

As against, if I myself wrote “E1 = E1 + E2”, then y would get incremented twice. But literally substituting x[y++] for E1, both times, y should be incremented twice.

Not sure I understand what is going on here.

Comment: As Hot Licks said, it is *NOT* a literal substitution. The storage location of E1 is only computed once, so the side effects involved in that computation (the increment, in this case) only occurs once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it had actually been

```
 E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))
```

Expression E1 is interpreted twice -- once on the right to compute the address to read the old value out of, and once on the left when computing the address to store the new value into. If E1 has side effects, they occur each time, and the two addresses may be different. (Though that's generally bad practice, since except for a few specific idioms it tends to badly confuse other humans reading the code -- if you must do it, and it isn't completely obvious what it's doing, be sure to provide comments explaining it!)

But since you wrote

```
 E1 op= E2
```

E1 is interpreted only once, to obtain the address from which the old value is read AND to which the new value is written. (Which is what you'd sorta expect since E1 only appears once in the compound assignment expression.) The side effects only occur once, and the address read from and written to are promised to be the same.